# Can we Iterate over list of Dynamic Components on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to iterate over list of dynamic components on visualforce page but its not working.

I tried with apex:repeat and apex:pageBlocktable tags on vf,
With transient keyword and without transient keyword.

vf page

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="testDynamicComponent    ">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:repeat value = "{!dynamicComponents}" var = "d">
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue = "{!d}"/>
</apex:repeat >
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller Extension

```
 public class testDynamicComponent {

    public testDynamicComponent(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

   public List<Component.Apex.InputField> getdynamicComponents()
    {
            List<Component.Apex.InputField> inputFieldList = new List<Component.Apex.InputField>();

            transient  Component.Apex.InputField inpField= new Component.Apex.InputField();
            inpField.expressions.value = '{!Account.Name}';
            inputFieldList.add(inpField);

            transient  Component.Apex.InputField inpFldIndus = new Component.Apex.InputField();
            inpFldIndus.expressions.value = '{!Account.Industry}';
            inputFieldList.add(inpFldIndus);

            return inputFieldList;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It's just showing blank screen.